# Php | How to pass unknown length array of arguments to function individually

Tags: php

I have an array of arguments that are in order for a function.

The number of items in the array differ. I want to be able to pass in each item in the array individually to the functions (eg...`func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);`). Opposed to just passing in the whole array.

Keep in mind, I do not know the length of the array, it differes depending on which function I am calling.

Comment: Do you mean PHP's splat operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since PHP 5.6 you have the [Variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) so you can call your function like this:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 5, "ten");
```

and you can send **all** the elements in the `$arr` to a function by calling it like this:

```
myFunc(...$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you have:

- [func_num_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)
- [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)
- [func_get_arg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php)

for that purpose.

**EDIT**

If you are fine using PHP 5.6 then you have splat operator. Quoting sample from docs ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)):

```
<?php
function add($a, $b, $c) {
    return $a + $b + $c;
}

$operators = [2, 3];
echo add(1, ...$operators);
```

Comment: I think his problem is how to to send the elements of a variable sized array to a function, so that the function will see those elements as individual parameters.

Comment: Perhaps you right. I edited the answer. Unfortunately I cannot upvote yours as I run out of my votes for today ;( Perhpas you should edit yours to make it more descriptive and clear then mine could be then deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have a function that its argument is an array, you can use `foreach` to fetch all the array elements:

```
function my_func($arg_array)
  {
  foreach($arg_array as $key=>$value)
    {
    ......
    }
  ....
  }
```

But if you mean you have a function that has unknown number of arguments you can use `func_get_args` function that returns an array containing arguments as an array.

```
function my_func()
  {
  foreach(func_get_args() as $key=>$value)
    {
    ......
    }
  ....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use : `call_user_func_array("functionName", $arrayofArgs);`

```
<?php

function unknown($arg1,$arg2,$arg3){
  echo "arg1 = $arg1 <br>";
  echo "arg1 = $arg2 <br>";
  echo "arg1 = $arg3 <br>";

}


$array = [
  "arg1" => "Hi",
  "arg2" => "Marhaba",
  "arg3" => "Hola",
  "arg4" => "foo"
];

call_user_func_array("unknown", $array);
 ?>
```

and you can call the function from class by passing the first param as array of ["className","methodName"]

> php Docs :
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: in php8 will throw error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $arg4